# The SelectCommand property has not been initialized before calling 'Fill'

Tags: sql, dataset, fill

The SelectCommand property has not been initialized before calling 'Fill'

I am getting this error when running StoredProcedure.ExecuteDataSet();

```
 DataSet ds= new DataSet();
        SqlDataAdapter ada = new SqlDataAdapter();
        try
        {
            ada.Fill(ds);
        }
        catch { }
```

Comment: private readonly IDataProvider provider;
private RACWebsite.RACWebsiteDB _db;

provider = ProviderFactory.GetProvider("Connection");
_db = new RACWebsite.RACWebsiteDB(provider.ConnectionString,provider.Name);

SubSonic.Schema.StoredProcedure sp = _db.GetCaseByID(CaseID);
DataSet ds = sp.ExecuteDataSet();

Comment: I was able to fix this issue by adding da.SelectCommand = cmd; before the fill

Answer (score 8):

I was able to fix this by adding the following code:

`[162] DbDataAdapter da = Factory.CreateDataAdapter();`
**`[163] da.SelectCommand = cmd;`**   <-- add this
`[164] da.Fill(ds);`

Hope this helps if anyone else had this problem...

Answer (score 3):

i was having this problem and that line made it work....

```
Protected Sub searchButton_Click(ByVal sender As Object, ByVal e As System.EventArgs) Handles searchButton.Click
    Try
        Dim dt As New Data.DataTable
        Dim con As New SqlConnection(ConfigurationManager.ConnectionStrings("connection1").ToString())
        Dim cmd As New SqlCommand("getAllPerson", con)
        cmd.CommandType = Data.CommandType.StoredProcedure

        cmd.Parameters.Add("@id", Data.SqlDbType.Int).Value = CInt(SearchBox.Text)

        Dim da As New SqlDataAdapter
        da.SelectCommand = cmd
        da.Fill(dt)

        fnameTextBox.Text = dt.Rows(0).Item("FName")
        lnameTextBox.Text = dt.Rows(0).Item("LName")
        dobTextBox.Text = dt.Rows(0).Item("DOB")
        addressTextBox.Text = dt.Rows(0).Item("Address")
        address1TextBox.Text = dt.Rows(0).Item("Address1")
        contactTextbox.Text = dt.Rows(0).Item("ContactNo")
    Catch ex As Exception
        MsgBox(ex.Message.ToString())
    End Try

End Sub
```