# Not getting any values while using "Like'

Tags: sql, vb.net

I have a form which takes input from the user in a TextBox to display ("contains") record/data on a grid. However, I am unable to achieve the input data thing. Database is MS Access. Everything else works fine.

I don't get any values in the form grid whatsoever for this query.

```
Imports System.Data.OleDb

Public Class Form1

    Dim dbConnection As OleDbConnection
    Dim dbCommand As OleDbCommand
    Dim dbDataAdapter As OleDbDataAdapter
    Dim ConnectString As String = "Provider = Microsoft.Jet.OLEDB.4.0;" & "Data Source=atg.mdb"
    Dim dtATG As DataTable
    Dim Searchq, SQLStr As String

    Private Sub Form1_Load(ByVal sender As System.Object, ByVal e As System.EventArgs) Handles MyBase.Load

    End Sub

    Private Sub Button2_Click(ByVal sender As System.Object, ByVal e As System.EventArgs) Handles Button2.Click
        Dim dtATG As New DataTable() ''// Create New Datatable

        Searchq = TextBox1.Text
        dbDataAdapter = New OleDbDataAdapter
        SQLStr = "SELECT * FROM ATG WHERE Term Like " & """%" & CStr(TextBox1.Text) & "%"""

        dbDataAdapter.Fill(dtATG)

        DataGrid1.DataSource = dtATG
    End Sub

End Class
```

Comment: you still need to tell de dataadapter to use that sql string

Answer (score 4):

What RDBMS are you using?

> SELECT * FROM ATG WHERE Term LIKE '%
>   *expression* %'

Don't pass values from text boxes directly into your query strings.

1. You didn't list any selection criteria, aka columns, you need to specify at least one column between SELECT and FROM or use the select all asterisk as I did above.
2. In you're LIKE clause you are using asterisks instead of modulo aka percent signs.  In SQL the field wildcard is % not *.
3. You're trying to build a string with values from a text box.  Unless that text box has validation in an event someone could enter:

> 123'; DROP TABLE ATG;

So your rendered string would be:

```
SELECT * FROM ATG WHERE Term LIKE '% 123'; DROP TABLE ATG; %'
```

Now technically that is invalid SQL, but the first two statements in the Query, if executed would delete the table from your database.  A good solution to this would be to check your form input before you pass the value into the SQL query and to use SQL Parameters to construct your query without worrying about people passing in malicious statements:

[Read here for OleDb samples using SQL Parameters](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bbw6zyha%28v=vs.71%29.aspx)

Passing malicious statements through interfaces to cause problems with RDMBS via SQL is known as SQL Injection.

Comment: Hi, could you provide a little more insight. Sorry, I'm just a beginner :)

Comment: Access is the database I'm using

Comment: Between `SELECT` and `FROM` you need to pass either a list of columns that you'd like to return or `*` to return everything.

Comment: Added more description as requested.  Let me know if this answers your question.

Comment: @Warfield - Thank you. I'm still getting an error which says "The SelectCommand property has not been initialized before calling 'Fill'." I have edited my code in the question. Any help is appreciated. Hope it's not asking for too much.

Comment: Checkout this SO post: [The SelectCommand property has not been initialized before calling 'Fill'](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2044466/the-selectcommand-property-has-not-been-initialized-before-calling-fill)